# How do I create Rust programs statically linked for musl on ARMv7 using Raspian/Debian?

Tags: rust, static-linking, armv7, musl

I am trying to create a statically linked version of a Rust program on ARMv7 (Raspian/Debian) by using the armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf target in Cargo. 
The build fails for the dependency backtrace-sys v0.1.28 with

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `backtrace-sys v0.1.28`
process didn't exit successfully: `/home/pi/develop/balena.io/migrate/target/debug/build/backtrace-sys-7330a27c773191d1/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
cargo:rustc-cfg=rbt
TARGET = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
HOST = Some("armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf")
CC_armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf = None
CC_armv7_unknown_linux_musleabihf = None
TARGET_CC = None
CC = None
CROSS_COMPILE = None
CFLAGS_armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf = None
CFLAGS_armv7_unknown_linux_musleabihf = None
TARGET_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("crt-static")
running: "arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-static" "-march=armv7-a" "-I" "src/libbacktrace" "-I" "/home/pi/develop/balena.io/migrate/target/armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf/debug/build/backtrace-sys-87487ee93f4ac0ac/out" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-DBACKTRACE_ELF_SIZE=32" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTED=1" "-DBACKTRACE_USES_MALLOC=1" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_THREADS=0" "-DBACKTRACE_SUPPORTS_DATA=0" "-DHAVE_DL_ITERATE_PHDR=1" "-D_GNU_SOURCE=1" "-D_LARGE_FILES=1" "-Dbacktrace_full=__rbt_backtrace_full" "-Dbacktrace_dwarf_add=__rbt_backtrace_dwarf_add" "-Dbacktrace_initialize=__rbt_backtrace_initialize" "-Dbacktrace_pcinfo=__rbt_backtrace_pcinfo" "-Dbacktrace_syminfo=__rbt_backtrace_syminfo" "-Dbacktrace_get_view=__rbt_backtrace_get_view" "-Dbacktrace_release_view=__rbt_backtrace_release_view" "-Dbacktrace_alloc=__rbt_backtrace_alloc" "-Dbacktrace_free=__rbt_backtrace_free" "-Dbacktrace_vector_finish=__rbt_backtrace_vector_finish" "-Dbacktrace_vector_grow=__rbt_backtrace_vector_grow" "-Dbacktrace_vector_release=__rbt_backtrace_vector_release" "-Dbacktrace_close=__rbt_backtrace_close" "-Dbacktrace_open=__rbt_backtrace_open" "-Dbacktrace_print=__rbt_backtrace_print" "-Dbacktrace_simple=__rbt_backtrace_simple" "-Dbacktrace_qsort=__rbt_backtrace_qsort" "-Dbacktrace_create_state=__rbt_backtrace_create_state" "-Dbacktrace_uncompress_zdebug=__rbt_backtrace_uncompress_zdebug" "-o" "/home/pi/develop/balena.io/migrate/target/armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf/debug/build/backtrace-sys-87487ee93f4ac0ac/out/src/libbacktrace/alloc.o" "-c" "src/libbacktrace/alloc.c"

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at '
```

I have tried this cross compiling from Ubuntu Linux x86_64 but also natively compiling on Raspian with the same result.

It looks like the setup is missing a compiler but I have no idea how to install and supply it.

Answer (score 1):

On the native platform, installing musl-dev and musl-tools packages and calling Cargo as follows led to a sucessful build:

```
CC=/usr/bin/musl-gcc cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf
```